# Copy and remove lines in Excel depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, automation, row

I have two sheets:

Sheet1 contains many rows with a lot of data in them. Each row has a unique number in column A.

All these data from the rows in sheet1 is copied to sheet2 with a simple =sheet1!$A$1 ect.

Sometimes/a lot of times I need more than one copy of the row (exact copy) in sheet2 and at the moment I am manually inserting a new line in sheet2 and I am copying the above row to the newly created row.

Now, it would be very nice and very time saving for me, if I in sheet1 could insert a new column, in which I could define how many copies that would have to be created in sheet2. It would also be nice, if I could change the number of copies afterwards (in sheet1), if I by mistake had punched in the wrong number there, and then excel automaticly would delete the number of copies that where to much, starting by the last row created.

Any ideas on how this could be made?

Code I have tried:

```
Sub copy()
Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set e = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim d
Dim j
d = 1
j = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("Q" & j))
  If i.Range("Q" & j) = "TERM" Then
    d = d + 1
    e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value
  End If
  j = j + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please share some of your code so we can help where you are stuck.  SO is not a code outsourcing platform.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Comment: I have tried some VBA with: `Sub copy()

Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set e = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim d
Dim j
d = 1
j = 2

Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("Q" & j))

If i.Range("Q" & j) = "TERM" Then
d = d + 1
e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value

End If
j = j + 1
Loop

End Sub`

Comment: That code did work, when I put in the TERM text in column Q, but all it does is copying the row from one sheet to another based on weather TERM is present or not. I would like it to copy multiple times based on the number in column Q.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be very efficient, but the way you could do that would be to have **TWO** extra columns in Sheet1.

1. As you stated, column B would be the number of repetitions you'd want the value from column A to be.
2. You'd want column C to be a cumulative count. To do this, you'd have:

   ```
   C1: =B1
   C2: =C1+B2
   ```

   Drag C2 down
3. Now, in sheet 2, you could put in the following formula **AS AN ARRAY FORMULA**

   ```
   A1: =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(TRUE,Sheet1!C:C>=ROW(),0))
   ```

   (To make it an array formula, once you type it in, finish with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.)
4. Drag, Sheet 2, A1 down for a lot of rows and that will update as you change the values in column B of sheet 1 (the number of times to repeat the value in Column A)

Hope this does the trick!

Comment: Seems to be great dissent on whether or not you should answer a question that is being down-voted due to "too broad" or not being proper for the site.  I see people coming down on both sides of the argument, but I have been told (when I post answers on bad questions) that I should refrain from answering because the question will eventually be put [on hold] or deleted.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? I am not able to figure out how this works. Where must I create columns and what data do I need to put into them. I have got the index line to work as an array formula.

Comment: @Chrismas007, I hear you, but while I completely agree a bad question should be downvoted, I simply don't understand why a good answer that works should be downvoted... It ends up confusing people who come to this question in the future and distrust the solution... Just my opinion... Simply put, downvote bad work, if I put in the effort and the question gets deleted, that's "punishment" enough... Again, I know it's probably not you who downvoted me, but that's my 2 cents on the matter!!

Comment: @JJ, I don't understand what you're asking... I pointed out step-by-step what you would need... Specifically look at step #2.

Comment: @JJ, to explain the formula - Sheet1 Column A = Values to put into sheet 2; Column B = Number of times to repeat each value in sheet 2; Column C = running total... Update the column references in the formula as necessary....

Comment: Okay, that is almost exactly what I am looking for and now it is working. The problem tho is, that I need the line to be copied from sheet2 to the next line in sheet2 and not from sheet1. Data from other sources are being put into the rows in sheet2, thats why I need a copy from the line in sheet2 and not a copy from the line in sheet1. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't understand... Aren't you copying that exact same value?? What difference does it make where you get it from?